# Are there data for the evolution of global economic inequality

Tags: inequality

Please excuse my ignorance of economics. I recently learned about the Gini-Coefficient as a measure of the economic inequality in a country. I have since seen several plots of this coefficient over time, each for an individual country. The following is from [Equality trust](https://www.equalitytrust.org.uk/about-inequality/scale-and-trends) and concerns the UK.
[image: United Kingdom, Gini over time]

Another plot, concerning various countries, is found [here](http://www.worldatnight.ethz.ch/content/images/figure6.11.png):
[image]

At first sight, it appears impossible, to construct such a curve for the entire world. Yet, in discussing extreme poverty,  I recently learned that incomes can be adjusted to equal purchasing power. Naively it seems, one could measure economic inequality globally. So, are there such data concerning the world as a whole? I know there are maps with countries colour coded by Gini, but this is not what I mean.

My interest is not limited to Gini, if there is another measure, by which the global temporal evolution of inequality can be captured, please tell me!

Comment: You may be able to find relevant information on Thomas Piketty's webpage. The data and charts from *Capital in the Twenty-First Century* are available there: http://piketty.pse.ens.fr/en/capital21c2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible, but it involves consiberable work as you need to collect underlying income distributions across the world or to be able to estimate them.

This has been done, for example in a World Bank policy research working paper 6719, *[Global Income Distribution From the Fall of the Berlin Wall to the Great Recession](http://documents.worldbank.org/curated/en/914431468162277879/pdf/WPS6719.pdf)* by Christoph Lakner and Branko Milanovic in December 2013. It included this chart of global income distributions:

[image: Global income distribution]

In fact the real story here is the reduction in the number of very-low-income people in absolute terms, especially in countries such as China over 20 years, plus the rise of middle incomes (in a global sense).

It is possible to use this to estimate Gini indices and the paper gives the following estimates:

- 1988: 72.2
- 1993: 71.9
- 1998: 71.5
- 2003: 71.9
- 2008: 70.5

Points to take from these numbers are

- global inequality is wide with a Gini index higher than almost all countries or regions
- the numbers suggest a global reduction in inequality even when inequality had been increasing within most major countries (especially China)
- the reduction has been small and can easily reverse (either in the future or on re-estimation of the past)

Regional trends and other inequality measures are in Table 3 of the paper, while other people's estimates of a global Gini index are in the Appendix Table 1.