# Statistical distribution of wages and wealth

Tags: macroeconomics, microeconomics, wages, wealth

How are wages distributed globally? Wages do not follow a normal distribution, do they? Is wealth distributed in the same way or differently?

Comment: Since wages cannot be negative, I would rather say that they follow a log-normal, truncated at the minimum (nominal) wages, or exponential maybe. I have no sources though. Also, if any answer does what you want, please consider ticking it as correct. A reputation of 1 is enough to do it. I remind you this because newcomers often forget to do so. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) That being said, welcome on [EC](https://economics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Related: https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/13097/are-there-data-for-the-evolution-of-global-economic-inequality

Answer (score 4):

***Globally***, there is Lakner and Milanovik (2015)'s elephant graph:

[image]

---

Hellebrandt and Mauro (2015)

[image]

**Thus, the two previous distributions look like bimodal log-normal distributions.**

---

or [CDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function)s, as in [MacAskill's book *Doing Good Better*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1592409660)

[image]

---

Did not find something strictly related to wages. For most of people, income may be a good proxy of wages.

Comment: I think it's fair to equate (gross) income to wages for the vast majority of the world population

Comment: Any question @ragingacademic ?

Answer (score 3):

Both distributions are often modelled log-normal, with a substantial number of zeros. A pareto distribution is also sometimes used ([Piketty & Saez (2012), p.32](https://eml.berkeley.edu/~saez/piketty-saezNBER12handbook.pdf)) for modelling the distribution of top incomes. Wealth distributions are also in general far more skewed than wage (or income) distributions.